# Class toggle working but rules not taking effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation div with a height of 0px, when I click a hamburger icon I want a class with 250px height to be added. I'm using an event listener to detect the click which is tested with an alert and working. `ToggleClass()` is then being used to add the class.

In the developer console I can see the class ebing added however the height of the div isn't changing and you can also see that the height rule isn't being detected/displayed in the console, even with a strikethrough.

Here is an image of the relevent info from dev console: https://gyazo.com/900f858cbfc41e9e8bfe00eb9fd8f1cb

styles.css:

```
#responsiveNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 27, 0.8);
    color: #009641;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.mobNavHeight {
    height: 250px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hamburgerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburgerBtn");

//DISPLAY MOBILE NAVIGATION ON HAMBURGER CLICK
    function displayMobNav() {
        alert("working");
        $('#responsiveNav').toggleClass("mobNavHeight");
    }

//EVENT LISTENERS
    hamburgerBtn.addEventListener("click", displayMobNav);


}); //Doc Ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a CSS specificity issue. An `id` has a higher specificity than a `class`. Use this in your CSS instead.

```
#responsiveNav.mobNavHeight {
    height: 250px;
}
```

But if I were you, I wouldn't use an `id` to target an element via CSS in the first place. Only use the `id` to target in javascript, but in CSS just use a class like `.responsiveNav`, move all of the `#responsiveNav` styles to that, then use `.mobNavHeight` to overwrite it. Like this.

```
<nav id="responsiveNav" class="responsiveNav">nav</nav>

.responsiveNav {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 27, 0.8);
    color: #009641;
    margin-top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.mobNavHeight {
    height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCoker working now. Do you mean ID has higher specificiy? becuase it was the id height that was being detected not the class

Comment: @EthanBristow yes sorry meant "higher", updated. Also updated with another suggestion just to not use id's in CSS in general, for this reason.